# Looping through 2 collections concurrently C#

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach

I parsed two different XML files that held information for customer orders by using LINQ to XML and passed the collection objects to another function to iterate through each collection concurrently and write information to an excel file.  I deleted some unnecessary code, but basically it's a foreach loop on the first collection addresses, then a nested foreach loop inside it on the products collection; however, it's not what I want because the foreach loop on the product collection doesn't run concurrently with the foreach loop over the addresses collection, instead it iterates over the entire products collection before moving on to the next position in the addresses collection.  How can I fix this?

```
    private static void WritetoExcel(IEnumerable<Address> addresses, IEnumerable<Address> products)
{
 foreach (var address in addresses)
               {

                    AddressLine1.Value2 = address.Name.ToUpper();
                    string a = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(address.AddressLine1);
                    AddressLine2.Value2 = a.ToUpper();
                    invoicenum.Value2 = "M" + num;
                    num++;

                    foreach(var product in products)
                    {
                        if (product.Title.Equals(sodiumChlorate))
                        {
                            UN.Value2 = "UN 1495, SODIUM CHLORATE";
                            HazardCode.Value2 = "3, PG II";
                            Package.Value2 = "500 GRAM BOTTLE";
                            FullName.Value2 = "SODIUM CHLORATE , ANALYZED ACS, REAGENT GRADE, CRYSTAL";
                            Box.Value2 = "PACKAGED ONE 500 GRAM BOTTLE PER BOX";
                            weight.Value2 = "12";
                            unitprice.Value2 = product.ItemPrice;
                            quantity.Value2 = product.Quantity;
                            unitship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            totalship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            decimal operand1 = decimal.Parse(product.ItemPrice);
                            decimal operand2 = int.Parse(product.Quantity);
                            total.Value2 = decimal.Multiply(operand1, operand2);
                        }
                        if (product.Title.Equals(semiNitric))
                        {
                            UN.Value2 = "UN2031, NITRIC ACID";
                            HazardCode.Value2 = "8, (5), PG II";
                            Package.Value2 = "2.5L POLY BOTTLE";
                            FullName.Value2 = "NITRIC ACID 70%, SEMICONDUCTOR, ELECTRONIC GRADE";
                            Box.Value2 = "PACKAGED 2.5L POLY BOTTLE PER BOX";
                            weight.Value2 = "12";
                            unitprice.Value2 = product.ItemPrice;
                            quantity.Value2 = product.Quantity;
                            unitship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            totalship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            decimal operand1 = decimal.Parse(product.ItemPrice);
                            decimal operand2 = int.Parse(product.Quantity);
                            total.Value2 = decimal.Multiply(operand1,operand2);
                       }
                        if (product.Title.Equals(acsNitric))
                        {
                            UN.Value2 = "UN2031, NITRIC ACID";
                            HazardCode.Value2 = "8, (5), PG II";
                            Package.Value2 = "2.5L POLY BOTTLE";
                            FullName.Value2 = "NITRIC ACID 70%, ACS, REAGENT GRADE";
                            Box.Value2 = "PACKAGED 2.5L POLY BOTTLE PER BOX";
                            weight.Value2 = "12";
                            unitprice.Value2 = product.ItemPrice;
                            quantity.Value2 = product.Quantity;
                            totalship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            unitship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            decimal operand1 = decimal.Parse(product.ItemPrice);
                            decimal operand2 = int.Parse(product.Quantity);
                            total.Value2 = decimal.Multiply(operand1, operand2);
                        }
                        if (product.Title.Equals(isopropyl))
                        {
                            UN.Value2 = "UN1219, ISOPROPANAOL";
                            HazardCode.Value2 = "3, PG II";
                            Package.Value2 = "QUART POLY BOTTLE";
                            FullName.Value2 = "ISOPROPYL ALCOHOL 99%, TECHNICAL GRADE";
                            Box.Value2 = "PACKAGED 4 X 1 POLY BOTTLE PER BOX";
                            weight.Value2 = "9";
                            unitprice.Value2 = product.ItemPrice;
                            quantity.Value2 = product.Quantity;
                            unitship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            totalship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            decimal operand1 = decimal.Parse(product.ItemPrice);
                            decimal operand2 = int.Parse(product.Quantity);
                            total.Value2 = decimal.Multiply(operand1, operand2);



                        }
                        if (product.Title.Equals(hazNitric))
                        {
                            UN.Value2 = "UN2031, NITRIC ACID";
                            HazardCode.Value2 = "8, (5), PG II";
                            Package.Value2 = "2.5L POLY BOTTLE";
                            FullName.Value2 = "NITRIC ACID 70%, ACS, REAGENT GRADE";
                            Box.Value2 = "PACKAGED 4 X 2.5L POLY BOTTLE PER BOX";
                            weight.Value2 = "33";
                            unitprice.Value2 = product.ItemPrice;
                            quantity.Value2 = product.Quantity;
                            unitship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            totalship.Value2 = product.ShippingPrice;
                            decimal operand1 = decimal.Parse(product.ItemPrice);
                            int operand2 = int.Parse(product.Quantity);
                            total.Value2 = decimal.Multiply(operand1, operand2);
                        }
                    }




                   if (address.AddressLine2 != null)
                    {

                        AddressLine3.Value2 = address.AddressLine2.ToUpper();
                        AddressLine4.Value2 = address.City.ToUpper() + ", " + address.State.ToUpper();

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        AddressLine3.Value2 = address.City.ToUpper() + ", " + address.State.ToUpper();
                        AddressLine4.Value2 = "";
                    }

                    FinalShipment.Value2 = "FINAL SHIPMENT TO " + address.City.ToUpper() + ", " + address.State.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Use Tasks, Threads, or PLINQ.  Pick one.

Comment: I'll read up on each of these, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the collections have the same length then checkout the linq extension .Zip(). This will let you compare both at the same time. Example:

```
var results = collection1.Zip(collection2, (a, b) => //check a against b
```

Comment: How would I incorporate this into my code? I changed my foreach loop to this:

`foreach (var address in addresses.Zip(products, (a, b) => new {a, b}))` but I'm getting this error on my code in this part              `AddressLine1.Value2 = address.Name.ToUpper();` saying: "Anonymous type #1" does not contain a definition for "Name" and no extension method "Name" accepting a first argument of type "AnonymousType#1" could be found.

Comment: I think I figured it out by using `AdressLine1.value2 = address.a.Name.ToUpper();`

Answer (score -1):

Your products iteration is inside the address iteration, so it's working fine to iterate first through the products, then the addresses. You can change the variables to IList I guess.

```
private static void WritetoExcel(IList<Address> addresses, IList<Address> products)
```

Then You can iterate through the two variables with the same for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < addresses.Count; i++) {
    // do something with addresses[i] and products[i]
```

this way You loop through the 2 variables not concurrently, but paralelly.

Br, Márton

Comment: I really want to accomplish this without changing the variables to IList and using a for loop.

Comment: You can still use the Zip answer. Accept that as answer.